# Confusion About Use of Trigonometric Identities & Compound Formulae

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I have a lecturer that has presented the following question as part of an assignment:

> Deduce that $$\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{5} \right)=\dfrac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{4} \tag 1$$

Naturally, I put these terms into a calculator and they do not appear to be equivalent (to my knowledge, anyhow).

What is he asking me to do here exactly? I assume the use of compound formulae and trigonometric identities is involved, but I have no idea where to start. The whole thing seems a bit vague to me.

Comment: This formula is correct. Tell us what you found. (And don't forget to switch to Radians mode.)

Comment: You are giving us a fragment of the question, when previous information has been provided. Do you expect us to read your mind ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust cos(2$\pi$/5) = x/2  and x^2 + x - 1 = 0

Comment: He is just asking you to solve the quadratic equation !!

Comment: Solved using the quadratic formula, there are two roots, one of which solves the equation. I'm concerned he'll penalise me for not using trigonometric identities in doing so.

Comment: No, the given instruction is to deduce the value of $x$ from what precedes. No trigonometric identity is involved. Things would have been much clearer if you had given the whole question.

Comment: Apologies. I am new to trigonometry and this exchange. I have a clear solution now. Will read up more on trigonometric identities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos(\frac{4\pi}{5})=\cos(2\pi-\frac{4\pi}{5})=\cos(\frac{6\pi}{5})$
If $x=\frac{2\pi}{5}$, we have $\cos(2x)=\cos(3x)$. Replacing by respective formulas, we have $$2\cos^2x-1=4\cos^3x-3cosx$$ Now replacing $\cos x$ by $t$, 
$$(t-1)(4t^2+2t-1)=0$$ We know that $t\neq 1$, so we solve the quadratic part and since $t>0$,

$t=\cos(\frac{2\pi}{5})=\frac{-1+\sqrt 5}{4}$

Edit: $t>0$, since $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{5})=\cos(72^\circ)$ and $\cos x\ge0, \; x \in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]. $

Comment: Thank you for replying but I wasn't asking for a solution, just an explanation of what he was asking me to do.

Comment: You may use some part as a hint, and get back if you are stuck at some point.

Comment: Considering the whole solution is there, it's difficult to ignore that while trying to figure it out for myself.

Comment: The main part that confuses me is how cos(2x) = cos(3x) is derived.

Comment: Use the fact that: $\cos(\theta)=\cos(2\pi -\theta)$. See the first line, then choose $x=\frac{2\pi}{5}$